# When loading from another form "Data type mismatch in criteria expression"

Tags: .net, ms-access, ms-access-2010, vb.net-2010

I'm having a trouble on how to solve the error "Data type mismatch in criteria expression"

I want to load staffs using another form but it prompts the error. I don't have any clue on how to solve this problem.

[Ms Access Table Design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YZeBR.png)

I think this line of code is where I get the said error :

```
Private Sub GetStaffRecord()
    Try
        sqL = "SELECT * From Staff WHERE StaffID = " & txtStaffID.Text & ""

        ConnDB()
        cmd = New OleDbCommand(sqL, conn)
        dr = cmd.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)
        If dr.Read = True Then
            txtStaffID.Text = dr("StaffID")
            txtLastname.Text = dr("Lastname")
            txtFirstname.Text = dr("Firstname")
            txtMI.Text = dr("MI")
            txtAddress.Text = dr("Address")
            txtContactNo.Text = dr("ContactNo")
            txtPosition.Text = dr("Position")
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message)
    Finally
        cmd.Dispose()
        conn.Close()
    End Try
End Sub
```

I'm really bad at english but I hope you can help me. Thank you so much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are missing quotes to enclose the text field 'txtStaffID'.  Use the following:

```
sqL = "SELECT * From Staff WHERE StaffID = """ & txtStaffID.Text & """"
```

Comment: You are a life savior sir! Thank you so much!